# Paypal conversions LATAM

Tags: php, paypal

If I’m selling products in Chile and all the product’s prices are listed in the local currency [CLP]. If I wish to provide a paypal option for abroad costumers, Should I list all my prices in paypal supported currencies? Or can I keep the list in Chilean pesos [CLP] and paypal will show the adequate equivalent in the available currencies the system supports?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the transaction info is transmitted to PayPal, it must be denominated in a PayPal-supported currency; typically USD is used.  So you need to know the amount you're going to charge in the supported currency you choose to receive, and tell PayPal that in your API communication or redirect.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, anyway I only have the supported currencies to indicate the price of the product..